# Flash player in firefox doesn't update playback device without a refresh

Tags: firefox, audio, windows-8.1, flash-player

In firefox, while a video (flash player) is playing, I cannot immediately change the playback device. After I set the new playback device, the video continues playing in the previous one, and a refresh of the page is needed in order to start playing in the new device.

However, in Chrome, Media Player, etc the device change is immediate and sound comes from the latest selected device.

I tried YouTube's videos on the Html5 player, and it's working fine (the device change is immediate). So apparently the problem is with Flash Player in Firefox

Is there a way to make firefox behave the same, or should I report it to mozilla?

Note: This is a behavior of Firefox 25 & 26 in Windows 8.1. In Windows 7 though, everything works fine